# matplotlib разделить маркеры

Tags: python, csv, графика, matplotlib

Есть файл CSV вида

```
1,0,enp0s31f6
1,0,enp0s31f6
2,0.286968124,enp0s31f6
3,0.347273802,enp0s31f6
4,0.376051415,enp0s31f6
5,1.895804954,enp0s31f6
6,2.03941807,eth0
7,2.061084575,enp0s31f6
8,3.026748561,enp0s31f6
9,3.247024689,enp0s31f6
10,3.896585252,eth0
11,4.001361629,enp0s31f6
12,4.216054934,enp0s31f6
13,4.26913004,eth0
14,4.26942665,enp0s31f6
15,4.463316773,enp0s31f6
```

Рисую график вот так:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x = []
y = []

with open('test.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(int(row[0]))
        y.append(float(row[1]))

plt.scatter(x,y, marker='o', label='Interfaces')
plt.xlabel('Packets')
plt.ylabel('Time')
plt.title('TEST')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Получаю на выходе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но на данной картинке только 1 вид маркеров (enp0s31f6 и eth0) вместе, как разделить их? Чтобы , к примеру, enp0s31f6 был синим маркером, а eth0 - оранжевым.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В первую очередь необходимо разделить исходные данные по признаку принадлежности к конкретному интерфейсу. Для этого можно использовать словарь, но так как чтение происходит из `csv` формата, удобнее будет воспользоваться готовыми инструментами (`numpy`, `pandas`).

Например, функция [recfromcsv](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html#shortcut-functions) из `numpy` позволяет получить исходные данные в виде [numpy.recarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html#numpy.recarray) с автоматическим определением типов.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.recfromcsv('test.csv', encoding=None, names=('time', 'packets', 'interface'))

# если в реальности интерфейсов будет больше, то надо добавить цветов
colors = 'blue', 'orange'
ifaces = np.unique(data.interface)  # множество интерфейсов

assert len(colors) == ifaces.size

for color, iface in zip(colors, ifaces):
    # получение данных, относящихся к текущему интерфейсу
    items = data[data.interface == iface]

    plt.scatter(items.time, items.packets, marker='o', label=iface, color=color)

plt.xlabel('Packets')
plt.ylabel('Time')
plt.title('TEST')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 3):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x = []
y = []
cl= []                                                    # +

with open('test.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(int(row[0]))
        y.append(float(row[1]))
        cl.append('r' if row[2]=='eth0' else 'g')         # +

plt.scatter(x,y, marker='o', c=cl, label='Interfaces')    # +  c=cl
plt.xlabel('Packets')
plt.ylabel('Time')
plt.title('TEST')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

По-моему проще всего решить эту задачу используя Pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Temp\test.csv', header=None, names=['x','y','name'])
df['col'] = np.where(df['name'] == 'enp0s31f6', 'blue', 'orange')
df.plot.scatter(x='x', y='y', c=df['col'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]